# MySQL: Insert into List

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a list attribute in my user entity. When I add test users, I get a null pointer exception when I want to add something to the list of this user (because there is no value in the list yet). If I add a blob when creating the user, the login does not work because the password is wrong

```
 INSERT INTO user_entity (id, last_name, first_name, email,
 telephone_number, password, country, Role, Status, version, want_information) VALUES
 (10, 'Datenschutz', 'Dieter', 'datenschutzbeauftrager@company.com', '01766666666',
'$2a$10$Sr6SDXQxBGi0hurRhz9Z8eTubESH.xYU6H2zD8c/ytAvoIqSowH5y',
'Deutschland',1,0,0, false);
```

Comment: please post your code as text not as image see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

According to wrong password. I assume you use Spring Security. By default Spring encrypts password using Bcrypt, so password should be stored like: `{bcrypt}encrypted_password`.
For development purpose you can use [this generator](https://bcrypt-generator.com/)

Comment: But the password is only invalid if I insert a blob in the column contact_persons. If the column is empty/null, the password is valid